# stored procedure in oracle with error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure placeorder(
  itemid in tempcart.item_id%type,num in integer,cid in customer_info.cust_id%type)
is
  cnt integer;
  amt integer;
  next_id number(5);
  temp tempcart%rowtype;
  cursor temp2 is select * from tempcart where tempcart.item_id=itemid;
  cursor temp1 is select * from tempcart;
BEGIN
  cnt:=0;
  select count(*) into cnt from porder;
  select max(oid) into next_id from porder;
  if(cnt=0) then
    next_id:=1;
  else
    next_id:=next_id+1;
  end if;
  if(num=1) then
    insert into corder values(next_id,itemid);
    select amount into amt from tempcart where item_id=itemid;
    insert into porder values(next_id,amt,sysdate); 
    open temp2;
    fetch temp2 into temp;
    insert into history values (itemid,temp.pid,temp.quantity,temp.amount,cid,temp.name);
  else
    amt:=0;
    open temp1;
    loop
      fetch temp1 into temp;
      exit when temp1%notfound;
      insert into corder values(next_id,temp.item_id);
      amt:=amt+temp.amount;
      insert into history values(temp.item_id,temp.pid,temp.quantity,temp.amount,cid,temp.name);
    end loop;
    insert into porder values(next_id,amt,sysdate);      
  end if;
end placeorder;
```

What's wrong with this procedure?  When I call it using `placeorder(1,1,2)` it just inserts values in `corder` but not in `porder`.

Comment: sorry...but i m actually new to plsql...please will u tell me how to debug this....i simply put dbms_output.put_line() after every line with some number and watched that it is getting executed till only insert into corder...why is that

Comment: When you say your code 'is getting executed till only `insert into corder`', what exactly do you mean?  Does your code hang?  Do you get an exception, and if so, what?  Or does the procedure appear to complete normally yet `porder` doesn't get inserted into?

Comment: @user2806673 - PL/SQL development tools, like Allround Automation's PL/SQL Developer (inexpensive) and Oracle's SQL Developer (free) make debugging a snap. Using SQL*Plus and DBMS_OUTPUT statements gets very tiring very fast, as you are discovering.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't reproduce this.

You haven't given us the tables you're using, nor any of the data in them, so I used the  tables

```
CREATE TABLE customer_info (cust_id INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE tempcart (item_id INTEGER, pid INTEGER, quantity INTEGER, amount INTEGER, name VARCHAR2(4000));

CREATE TABLE corder (oid INTEGER, itemid INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE porder (oid INTEGER, amt INTEGER, order_date DATE);

CREATE TABLE history (itemid INTEGER, pid INTEGER, quantity INTEGER, amount INTEGER, cid INTEGER, name VARCHAR2(4000));
```

and data

```
INSERT INTO tempcart (item_id, pid, quantity, amount, name) VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 'test 1');
```

I then ran

```
EXEC placeorder(1, 1, 2);
```

After doing that, I could verify that `corder` and `porder` were both being inserted into, as was the `history` table:

```
SQL> select * from corder;

       OID     ITEMID
---------- ----------
         1          1

SQL> select * from porder;

       OID        AMT ORDER_DAT
---------- ---------- ---------
         1          4 03-OCT-13

SQL> select * from history;

    ITEMID        PID   QUANTITY     AMOUNT        CID
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          2          3          4          2
test 1
```

Therefore, it's difficult to see what your problems could be.

I notice that you are not closing your cursors `temp1` and `temp2`.  Try closing them immediately after you've finished with them, using `CLOSE temp1` and `CLOSE temp2`.

Comment: @user2806673: what triggers do you have on your tables?  Does it help if you disable them all?  Without seeing these triggers you speak of I can only guess at what your problem is.  You are making it very difficult for anyone to help you.